# Assign multiple functions to a button

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to assign multiple functions to a button but when I do that it doesn't change the button text but executes the second function. It edits the text when I only connect the setText function. That's the code snipped:

```
ui.button_start.clicked.connect(lambda: ui.button_start.setText("Stop"))
ui.button_start.clicked.connect(lambda: bot.accept_request(loop=True))
```

I already searched on the Internet and they say that it should work, but it doesn't: (

I think I also have to say that accept_request() opens a URL in chromedriver, but the weird thing is is that it doesn't edit the text even when I call the editText function before the Selenium call (the Selenium call works).

Comment: Why do you have the `tkinter` tag?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a third function that calls the other two and let the button execute only the `helper` function:

```
def helper():
   ui.button_start.setText("Stop")
   bot.accept_request(loop=True)

ui.button_start.clicked.connect(helper)
```

Comment: it still doesnt work (i edited my question)

Comment: @falk2 then provide a [mre]

Comment: @ArcKoor lambda is unnecesary, use `ui.button_start.clicked.connect(helper)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, with two lines:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QApplication, QWidget


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        btn = QPushButton(self, text="Hello World")

        # This, with two lines
        btn.clicked.connect(self.func_1)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.func_2)

    def func_1(self):
        print("The Button Was Clicked! (Function 1)")

    def func_2(self):
        print("The Button Was Clicked! (Function 2)")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

It's much cleaner than writing a function which calls another two functions.

Comment: that's what i did, but it still doesnt work (i also edited my question)

Comment: This has been working for me, can you try just this code snippet (on its own without your other code to see if it works)? That way we can try and narrow down the problem.

Comment: @falk2 then provide a  [mre]